# Report of all trac tickets that are not prioritized by a certain user

Tags: sql, report, trac

I use prioritisation for all tickets in Trac. All new tickets have to be prioritized by our ***Admin*** user.

While a ***normal user*** creates a new ticket, he/she can already prioritize the ticket, but that can be quite arbitrary sometimes. ***Admin*** should look through all prioritisations by himself.

Is it possible to select only those tickets, that are **not prioritized by Admin** himself?

---

I am quite near already:

```
-- union tickets initially prioritized by another than Admin and not changed ever since:
 SELECT 
   milestone AS __group__,
   t.id AS ticket,
   summary,
   reporter as prioritizer,
   component, version, status, t.priority, severity, milestone,
   t.type AS type, 
   t.time AS created,
   changetime AS _changetime, 
   description AS _description,
   reporter AS _reporter
  FROM ticket t
  WHERE priority <> 'average' 
   AND reporter not IN ('admin','other_admin')
   AND status <> 'closed'
   AND t.id NOT IN (
       SELECT ticket FROM ticket_change WHERE field='priority' 
   )
UNION
-- with all changes made by others:
 SELECT 
   milestone AS __group__,
   t.id AS ticket, 
   summary,
   c.author as prioritizer, 
   component, version, status, t.priority, severity, milestone,
   t.type AS type, 
   t.time AS created,
   changetime AS _changetime, 
   description AS _description,
   reporter AS _reporter
  FROM ticket_change c, ticket t
  WHERE t.id=c.ticket and field='priority' 
   AND author not IN ('admin','other_admin')
   AND status <> 'closed'
ORDER BY milestone, author, prioritizer
```

But that has a lot of tickets, that are corrected by Admin already by now.

---

How can I select only those tickets, where **the last prioritization** (or initial if the only one) is  **not made by Admin himself**?

I made that a sepyrate Question here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647694/trac-report-that-shows-the-author-of-the-last-prioritization-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to distinguish that with an individual Trac query.

This is how you create such special query (with permissions to create queries). Unfortunately, it's too special to create such query with the GUI elements on page "Individual Query". These are the steps:

1. Select "View Tickets" from the main menu
2. click the "Create New Report" button, you'll get to the edit page then
3. Set a title like "All tickets modified (but not by Admin)"
4. Put this SQL query in the "Query for report" edit field:

   SELECT id,reporter FROM ticket WHERE priority <> 'average' AND reporter not IN (SELECT username FROM permission WHERE action='TRAC_ADMIN')

   or this one to see ticket changes made by users who aren't admins:

   SELECT ticket,author FROM ticket_change WHERE field='priority' and author not IN (SELECT username FROM permission WHERE action='TRAC_ADMIN')
5. Save the report and it'll get a new report number
6. Click that report on the report page (go to there with a click on main menu item "View Tickets"), and there you go!

The inner SELECT gets all admins from the permission database table, the outer SELECT finds all tickets created/changed by people not being one of the admins. Database table ticket_change also has a column 'time' you can use to extend your SQL query for adding a condition like "only changes of the latest n days" or something like that.

Comment: this works, but only if someone changed the priority. I search for tickets, that have an initial priority set other than "average" and not by Admin

Comment: You're right, rubo77. I've edit it and added the creation query. Have a look into the database (with e.g. SQLite Database Browser) to see that all new tickets are logged in table "tickets" and there is a column "priority" and "reporter" you must check for your conditions.

Comment: you can use UNION to create one report like this: `SELECT id,summary,reporter as prioritizer 
      FROM ticket 
      WHERE priority <> 'average'
      AND reporter not IN (SELECT username FROM permission WHERE action='TRAC_ADMIN')
    UNION
    SELECT ticket,summary,author as prioritizer 
      FROM ticket_change WHERE field='priority' 
      and author not IN (SELECT username FROM permission WHERE action='TRAC_ADMIN')`